# select n records from nth record in linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, entity, ienumerable

I am searching for something like LIMIT(10, 10) <- thats how it works in php

```
Products = Products.Take(10).ToList();
```

That's not what i want because I want to skip first 10 records .

does anybody know how i can do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx)

```
Products = Products.Skip(10).Take(10).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 Products = Products.Skip(10).Take(10).ToList();
```